# What permissions does GITHUB_TOKEN require for releases from a GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to limit the scope of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` actions on my repository have access to. One such action creates a draft release in my repository -- and I would like it only to be able to create that draft and nothing else.

Taking a look at the available permissions here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions there isn't one specifically for releases (or even tagging really). Is it considered a "deployment"? Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 15):

To allow your GitHub Action creating a draft release, you will have to grant your `GITHUB_TOKEN` access to [`POST /repos/:owner/:repo/releases`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-release) using the [`contents: write`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions) permission.

Unfortunately this permission is quite broad and allows writing all other content related stuff like commits, jobs, branches, etc. There is no fine grained scope permission that only allows creating a draft release.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/permissions-required-for-github-apps#permission-on-contents

Note that Personal Access Token (PAT) have the same problem with a broad [`repo` scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes):

> Grants full access to repositories, including private repositories.
> That includes read/write access to code, commit statuses, repository
> and organization projects, invitations, collaborators, adding team
> memberships, deployment statuses, and repository webhooks for
> repositories and organizations. Also grants ability to manage user
> projects.

Comment: Setting least privilege permissions for the GITHUB_TOKEN is an OSSF/Scorecards check. You can use the guidance at https://github.com/ossf/scorecard/blob/main/docs/checks.md#token-permissions

Answer (score 3):

As explained through [the GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions), the `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have all available permissions.

If you want to perform specific operations in your workflows involving other permissions, you'll need to create a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) with the wished permissions and use it instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

[Reference from the GitHub Community about `GITHUB_TOKEN` scope](https://github.community/t/github-actions-token-scope/17061/2)

Comment: That seems to only have extremely broad scopes, and very few scopes actually useful for CI actions.

Comment: It's true those PAT permissions are quite broad. But as what you're looking for is among one of them, creating a token using a PAT can resolve what you're trying to do.

Comment: I see, but I can still technically use the github_token as I was previously with pretty broad access. In that case, using a different token with similarly broad access isn't really my goal.

Comment: Yes. Depending on the operation, the `github_token` is enough. However, the scope with the `PAT` is wider so sometimes you might need it instead of the `github_token`.

Comment: Using a PAT creates a dependency on a single user's account. It's a bad practice if you're not working on a personal project.

Comment: Note that in an Organization, you can create a **Service User Account** for the whole Org, that could be use to share secrets internally without having the trouble of the user leaving the Org.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider creating a "New Fine-Grained" Personal-Access Token (PAT) with "Contents" permissions