# How to upload a release in GitHub Action using github-script action

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Now that some of the standard GitHub actions have been archived and are no longer supported I need to create a new release and upload the artefacts using the [GitHub Script](https://github.com/actions/github-script) action.

> NOTE: I can't use actions that are not supported by GitHub.

I've got the release done and working, but now when trying to upload a release artefact I cannot find a way to upload the content of the release (which is a tarball).

The [documentation](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v19#repos-upload-release-asset) for the API endpoint for uploading the release asset suggests the data should be a part of the input to the call rather than referencing a file.

How do I get the contents of the file into the data argument below:

```yaml
- name: Upload Assets
  uses: "actions/github-script@v6"
  with:
    script: |
        try {
          return await github.rest.repos.uploadReleaseAsset({
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            name: "release.tar.xz",
            release_id: ${{ fromJSON(steps.deploy.outputs.result).data.id }}
            data: 
          })
        } catch (error) {
          core.setFailed(error.message);
        }
```

Comment: Can you not use the [upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) action?

Comment: @Azeem No because that uploads artefacts to the workflow and not release assets to a release that is created earlier in the workflow. But thanks.

Comment: @Azeem Can you please not edit spellings - artefact is the correct spelling and did not need editing

Comment: I've used the gh cli to do these things as it encapsulates a lot of this functionality in a simple set of calls. Not sure if that would be permitted in your environment. https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create & https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_upload

Comment: Guessing here I assume you'd need to: `fs = require('fs');` and then `data: fs.readFileSync(...)`.

Comment: @jessehouwing Have no problem with the `gh` cli - this works great. Add env var for the github token and do the release. That works really nicely. Much better than the cURL I'd come up with! Do you want to do a quick answer because I think that's the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A great way to create releases and other GitHub actions, is the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/) (`gh`).

The GitHub workflow already has a GitHub token `${{ github.TOKEN }}` and you can pass it to the env, the CLI will automatically pick it up.

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  release:
    steps:
      - run: |
          gh release create v1.2.3 release.tar.xz
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.TOKEN }}
        shell: bash
        name: Creates a release in GitHub and uploads attachments
```

> Note: For some reason, `gh` will do one call to see if the file is already uploaded, the another call to upload the file. So I've burned through the API rate limits using this approach trying to attach 500 files to a release. Normally you should be able to do 1000 API calls per hour across workflows.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really neat way of creating the release with the upload at the same time in GitHub actions.

Comment: Doesn't it need `contents: 'write'` in  `permissions`?

Comment: Correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69941765/736079, the token used to get all write permissions by default, the new default doesn't contain write, and you must explicitly add it.

Answer (score 2):

`gh` is a good solution. Or, if still needed to work with `github-script`, I confirmed that the following worked somehow (at least for a small file -- not tested with a large file, though), jfyi.

```
jobs:
  publish:
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
    # ...
    - name: Upload an Asset in GitHub Release
      uses: "actions/github-script@v6"
      with:
        github-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
        script: |
          const fs = require('fs').promises;
          await github.rest.repos.uploadReleaseAsset({
            name: 'README.md',
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            release_id: ${{ env.RELEASE_ID }},
            data: await fs.readFile('./README.md')  # The file to upload.
          });
```