# How to troubleshoot a semantic-release permission denied error?

Tags: github-actions, npx

I get this error when running workflow:

```
Run npx semantic-release
sh: 1: semantic-release: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.
```

Any help please on how to enter secrets for `github_token`.

I was expecting to do a new release.

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  terraform-workflow:
    permissions:
      contents: write
      issues: write
      pull-requests: write
    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install

    - name:  Setup Terraform
      uses: HashiCorp/setup-terraform@v2
      with:
        terraform_version: 1.1.9
    
    - name: init
      run: terraform init

    - name: fmt
      run: terraform fmt
    
    - name: validate
      run: terraform validate

    - name: plan
      run: terraform plan

    - name: release
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: npx semantic-release
        
    - name: apply
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve

    - name: destroy
      run: terraform destroy -auto-approve
```

Comment: Please include your workflow in your question. Have you configured the `permissions` properly in it for releases i.e. `contents:write`? See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67389957/what-permissions-does-github-token-require-for-releases-from-a-github-action

Comment: I have edited the question and included the workflow

Comment: Your workflow looks fine. No issues, apparently. What is the output of `ls -l $(which npx)`? You can add this before running `npx semantic-release` command.

Comment: got this;  Run ls -l $(which npx)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jul 10 10:08 /usr/local/bin/npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
sh: 1: semantic-release: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.

Comment: That above output looks good. If you could create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a public repo, that would be very helpful to test and identify the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 'npx' package with 'yarn' to run the semantic-release to automate the versioning and publishing of your project. That might work.